# Find multiple strings in same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find two different string in the same cell, and according to the result, past the relevant result.

I have this formula     `=LEFT(TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(E2,FIND("pplix",E2)+13,12),"=>",""),":",""),"=",""))),7)`

It'works fine, my goal is to search the word `"itsm"` in the same cell and sort the the result associated if it cannot find `"pplix"`.

I expect to use somthing like below with the ***IF*** function: 
`=LEFT(TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(E2,FIND("itsm",E2)+13,12),"=>",""),":",""),"=",""))),7)`

I hope that's clear.

Comment: Actually it's not clear at all :p
Can you please provide a sample input and required output?

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if this can help:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("pplix",E3))),LEFT(TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(E3,FIND("itsm",E3)+13,12),"=>",""),":",""),"=",""))),7),LEFT(TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(E3,FIND("itsm",E3)+13,12),"=>",""),":",""),"=",""))),7))
```

let me know

Comment: Facing error message "more level of nesting than are allowed"

Comment: @excell_noob it is not possible, it is working in my example sheet. check if you are not missing any paranthesis or any comma or an extra one.